# Bootstrap typeahead not working in agGrid

Tags: typeahead.js, ag-grid, bootstrap-typeahead

I have created a page which renders an agGrid with 2 columns (City, Country). I have made the 'City' column as a typeahead using 'cellEditor' name 'TypeaheadCellEditor'. Inside this cellEditor, I am invoking the typeahead code using local data, but it doesn't work. I tried inspecting the DOM, the ul for typeahead suggestions are not visible.

```
function TypeaheadCellEditor() {}
TypeaheadCellEditor.prototype.init = function(params) {
  this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
  this.eInput.setAttribute("id", "search1");
  this.eInput.setAttribute("data-provide", "typeahead");
  this.eInput.setAttribute("data-items", "4");
  this.eInput.setAttribute("class", "span3");
  this.eInput.value = params.value;
  var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
  $('#search1').typeahead({  
    source: subjects
  })
};
```

At the same time,  I have used the same typeahead code in a text box above this grid, it works there. I have the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0kMK0bbebUOLbhZwmMkV?p=preview)

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting

Comment: There is no error in the console. You can run the demo in the link I have posted (link to plnkr).https://plnkr.co/edit/0kMK0bbebUOLbhZwmMkV?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked your plunker and modified it to get the typeahead to work: https://plnkr.co/edit/ICd8Oue3AmYusgGHLgS2?p=preview

Two changes:

- I've made the editor a popup editor so that the typeahead dropdown can be displayed

  ```
  TypeaheadCellEditor.prototype.isPopup = function () {
      return true;
  };
  ```
- I populate the typeahead in afterGuiAttached - before this the element might not exist in which case jquery wont find it

  ```
  // focus and select can be done after the gui is attached
  TypeaheadCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
      var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
      $('#search1').typeahead({
        source: subjects
      },'json')
      this.eInput.focus();
  };
  ```

This will work now if you double click in a cell, type "P" for example and select an item with the mouse.

You'll probably want to listen to (and override) keyboard events to allow for up/down arrow keys otherwise the grid will treat these as grid navigation operations

Comment: [Angular typeahead inside ag-grid](http://plnkr.co/edit/7z4VsCYpOqGB6dzO536G?p=preview)

Comment: [Bootstrap3 typeahead inside ag-grid](http://plnkr.co/edit/0kMK0bbebUOLbhZwmMkV?p=preview)